# chrome issue - jquery play() control

Tags: jquery, html, video, playback, mediaelement.js

Ok,

I am using medialement.js to play and control a video.
The purpose is very simple. I play the video once I click over the cover image of the video.
It works fine in Firefox, in IE I still have to allow it or something but in Chrome the video turns invisible after clicking over the cover.

```
$("document").ready(function() {

    $("video").click(function() {

    player2.play();
    $("nav").delay(4500).fadeIn(3000);

    });

});
```

an online sample can be found at evo.lopezi.com

Comment: try removing this n ry once   $("nav").delay(4500).fadeIn(3000);

Comment: had tried that before, doesn´t work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug in chrome, you can make it appear by clicking. Try adjusting the video element, by doing something like this before playing (or changing its opacity):

```
$('#player2').attr('controls', true);
$('#player2').attr('controls', false);
player2.play();
```